# I want to install Mono 5.0.0 on Debian 8

Tags: linux, mono, debian

I'm quite new to Debian and now I wanted to install Mono 5.0.0 on Debian 8 in order to run some programs, which require Mono 5.0.0, but I don't have a clue how to install Mono. Currently I've got installed Mono 4.8.1, but what do I have to to, in order to update this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 5.0.0.61 is available, Debian install instructions @ http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives If you are looking for CI builds : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/

Comment: If i do that, it still says mono 4.8.1 ?

Comment: i need to install the alpha version of 5.0.0

Comment: Version **5.0.0.61-0xamarin1+debian8b1** is available:  http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/pool/main/m/mono/?C=S;O=A make sure that you have enabled the correct policy: https://askubuntu.com/a/428778

Answer (score 0):

See the recent announcement here about Linux packages: http://www.mono-project.com/news/2017/04/24/mono-linux-package-repository-changes-beginning-with-5-0/